# Exception is not getting defined

Tags: c#, exception

I am trying to create a new custom exception.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace project1.Exception
{
  public class ItemNotFoundException: Exception
  {
  }
}
```

When building the project it is giving an error.

> Error  51  'Solution1.project1.Exception' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'   D:\wORKsHOP\Arte.Apax2 08.05.2015\project1\Attributes\Logger.cs 71  80  Solution1.project1

Any idea why it is happening? Do I need to add something like `System.exception`?

Comment: Shiow us `Logger.cs`, as that is where the error is occurring.

Comment: Avoid using namespace names which are used as class names also. Namespaces group a collection of classes with equal purposes, so mostly you can use a plural of the common part of your classes inside. In this case this probably would be `namespace project1.Exceptions`.

Answer (score 3):

Rename `namespace project1.Exception` to `namespace project1.MyCustomException` or some such. The compiler is seeing `Exception` in

```
public class ItemNotFoundException: Exception
```

as referring to your namespace, `Exception`, rather than the class. Renaming your namespace to anything other than `Exception` will fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The name space that you are using is called

```
namespace project1.Exception
```

within this namespace you are using an inheritance of Exception. The problem with this is that the compiler thinks that your

```
public class ItemNotFoundException: Exception
```

is refering to the namespace and not the Exception standard class.
To fix this, simply write

```
public class ItemNotFoundException: System.Exception
```

And it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You created a name ambiguity by calling your namespace `Exception`. Now the compiler does consider the namespace naming more important than the object named `Exception` inside the `System` namespace. Consequently it warns you about inheriting from a namespace instead of an object. If you want to inherit System.Exception in such a namespace you need to full qualify the inherited objects name including its namespace to resolve the ambiguity.

```
namespace project1.Exception
{
  public class ItemNotFoundException: System.Exception //Fullqualified reference to exception
  {
  }
}
```

Of course you can also simply rename your namespace to not contain `Exception`, as mentionend earlier - then you can live without the fullqualified name.